# Solr search in multiple fields in drupal 7

Tags: solr, drupal-7

Now apachesolr search works only in content. It also have to work on other fields 
for eg: on typing "test", It searches only in content.

My requirement is  to search on description,label also (which i have already indexed).
`content:abcd OR description:sample_upload_document`

I tried by using apachesolr_query_prepare($query)

```
function filedepot_apachesolr_query_prepare(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {

     $query->addParam('qf','content description');
     watchdog('solr result',print_r($query,true));

}
```

refering to the site`http://knackforge.com/blog/selvam/drupal-7-filtering-solr-results`.
After performing that, i found description is added to

```
SolrBaseQuery Object
    (
        [params:protected] => Array
            (
                 [qf] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => content^40
                        [1] => description
                    )
```

But still when i give the value for description, search results would not yield any value.

Am i correct in a way? why doesnt it return the result?

How to do that? default search,searches the given text only in content.How to make it to search on other fields like description,label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which parser it is using. If it is using standarad query parser, then `qf` parameter wont work. The `qf` parameter works in DisMax Parser.